# Get day chart data in csv format at yahoo finance

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

is there a way to get the data presented by this chart:

[http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=EURUSD%3DX+Interactive#symbol=EURUSD=X;range=1d](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=EURUSD=X%20Interactive#symbol=EURUSD=X;range=1d)

in csv format? I mean for e.g. what was the value of given stock/bond etc every minute? I know you can use queries to yahoo using something like

`http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=`

but I'm looking for a way to get a detailed daily chart numerical data (only one stock exchange day), as seen on above link. As far as I know table can give minimum resolution of one day, this does not satisfy my. I've tried to use the link above and mix it with the 'table' or 'quotes' and so on, but with no luck.

As a bonus I'd be really happy to be able to take some historical days data like above, but just current day data will be fine if getting history is impossible.

**Edit**

Yahoo is not a necessity - any cvs or other easily parsable format from other sites will do (as long as it's free and up to date - max 15 minutes old).

thanks for any suggestions,

kajman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the financial api, in some way like that:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=
```

And the historical data you can get by:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=
```

Or you can use YQL (Yahoo query language) Not CSV, but very usable:

http://www.gurchet-rai.net/dev/yahoo-finance-yql

Comment: This is an outdated problem. Eventually I was asking yahoo for needed data every 5 minutes or so and then created needed data. I was using something similar to links you provided. Thanks for your input.